# import a sound externally or from the library? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

I was wondering which is better. Import an external sound to load using codes, or import a sound from the library using codes?

Answer (score 0):

## Loading sound external

- keeps the swf lightweight
- swf can start faster (just before the sound is loaded)
- if the sound-url is injected or provided by xml you could change the sound without doing changes in the swf/source
- `mp3s` were loaded and played natively
- other formats like `wav` need additional code-libaries

## Importing sound in libary

- swf will be bigger
- swf needs longer to load
- changing the sound requires changes on the the source an recompiling the swf
- formats `mp3` and `wav` are possible to include in a native way
- it is possible to synchronize sound on a timeline directly in the FLASH IDE

Maybe forgot something ;-)
Greetings.

Comment: SO In conclusion its better to load sound externally?

Comment: The real question is about your requirements and usage. If you need to keep the file small and only need the sound on a specific part or you'll need to change every week the url of the sound: you could choose the external way. If the filesize doesnt matter and/or the longer main-loading-process useful or loading is not desired at runtime: go the other way.

Comment: Im creating a test game app that plays sounds like clock ticking, buzzer, alarm, etc... so my sounds are fixed and doesnt need to be replaced..

Comment: In this case add it to your libary and have fun! Greetings